# Sending string and see if value existed in database using Express

Tags: mysql, angularjs, node.js, express

I'm sending from client side and making query to database using express to find that person, I'm not sure how to search string from database. Any idea what is going wrong with the code below?

**search.html**

```
<div class="row form-group">
            <label for="searcWorker" class="col-md-3">Search Worker:</label>
            <div class="col-md-7">
                <input class="form-control" ng-model="vm.searchString" type="text"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="searchPerson()">Search</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**ctrl.js**

```
$scope.searchPerson = function(){
        console.log($scope.vm.searchString);
        workerFactory.getPerson($scope.vm.searchString).then(function(response){
            console.log(response);
        });
    }
```

**factory.js**

```
getPerson:function(personName){
            return $http.get('/getPerson' , personName);
            console.log('FACTORY', personName);
        }
```

**express.js**

```
app.get'/getPerson', function(req,res){
  connection.query('SELECT * FROM worker_table', function(err, rows, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    Obj = rows;
  });
  res.send(Obj);
});
```

Comment: What type of database are you using?

Comment: Looks like your sending the response outside the callback.  `Obj` will not be valid.

Comment: I am using mysql database

Answer (score 1):

Only commenting on the express part:

```
app.get'/getPerson', function(req,res){
  connection.query('SELECT * FROM worker_table', function(err, rows, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    Obj = rows;
  });
  res.send(Obj);
});
```

should be, assuming that connection is a valid object and you have set it up correctly:

```
app.get('/getPerson', function(req, res) {
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM worker_table', function(err, rows) {
        if(err) { 
            res.sendStatus(500); // internal server error, you could also return a 
                                 // JSON, please notice that it is important to release the connection when it 
                                 // errors, you could log the error right afterwards
            console.log(err.stack); 
        } else {
            res.send(rows);
        }
    });
});
```

Please notice that now your object is being called within the query, you wouldn't have received the data because connection.query is an async call.

Good luck.